# MSSQL ORDER BY with OFFSET and FETCH NEXT do not work properly

Tags: sql-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [id]
      ,[name]
      ,[dob]
FROM [Production].[dbo].[test]
ORDER by [dob] ASC
```

Result:

| id | name | dob |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Danny Small | 1/1/2009 |
| 3 | Victor Brady | 1/1/2009 |
| 4 | Maximus Hoffman | 1/1/2009 |
| 9 | Rosa Braun | 1/1/2009 |
| 10 | Marley Chapman | 1/1/2009 |
| 11 | Cristian Chaney | 1/1/2009 |
| 6 | Shayla Farrell | 1/1/2009 |
| 7 | Tom Summers | 1/1/2009 |
| 15 | Madison Reid | 1/1/2009 |
| 16 | Nelson Green | 1/1/2009 |
| 18 | Dalton Duran | 1/1/2009 |
| 24 | Karina Giles | 1/1/2009 |
| 25 | Jon Jon | 1/1/2009 |
| 17 | Riya Webster | 1/3/2009 |
| 12 | Alexus Cisneros | 1/3/2009 |
| 13 | Ann Mcclure | 1/3/2009 |
| 14 | Aryan Cortez | 1/3/2009 |
| 5 | Stefan Tamburyn | 1/3/2009 |
| 23 | Dalton Duran | 1/3/2009 |
| 2 | Eva Hobbs | 1/5/2009 |
| 8 | Elliott Acosta | 1/5/2009 |
| 22 | Kadin Mcclure | 1/5/2009 |

Now I want to get first 10 records:

```
SELECT [id]
      ,[name]
      ,[dob]
FROM [Production].[dbo].[test]
ORDER by [dob] ASC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Result:

| id | name | dob |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Danny Small | 1/1/2009 |
| 11 | Cristian Chaney | 1/1/2009 |
| 10 | Marley Chapman | 1/1/2009 |
| 9 | Rosa Braun | 1/1/2009 |
| 4 | Maximus Hoffman | 1/1/2009 |
| 3 | Victor Brady | 1/1/2009 |
| 7 | Tom Summers | 1/1/2009 |
| 6 | Shayla Farrell | 1/1/2009 |
| 15 | Madison Reid | 1/1/2009 |
| 16 | Nelson Green | 1/1/2009 |

Now I want to get second 10 records:

```
SELECT [id]
      ,[name]
      ,[dob]
FROM [Production].[dbo].[test]
ORDER by [dob] ASC
OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Result:

| id | name | dob |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | Tom Summers | 1/1/2009 |
| 6 | Shayla Farrell | 1/1/2009 |
| 25 | Jon Jon | 1/1/2009 |
| 5 | Stefan Tamburyn | 1/3/2009 |
| 14 | Aryan Cortez | 1/3/2009 |
| 13 | Ann Mcclure | 1/3/2009 |
| 12 | Alexus Cisneros | 1/3/2009 |
| 17 | Riya Webster | 1/3/2009 |
| 23 | Dalton Duran | 1/3/2009 |
| 22 | Kadin Mcclure | 1/5/2009 |

As you can see records:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | Tom Summers | 1/1/2009 |
| 6 | Shayla Farrell | 1/1/2009 |

are duplicated in first 10 records and second 10 records.
I understand that `ORDER BY` is messing around.

Solution could be adding another `ORDER BY` but what if have to use only one column to `ORDER BY` and some cells may have same value?

Comment: It's working as expected, you have no tiebreaker. As all the rows have the *same* value for `dob` you are getting 10 **arbitrary** rows.

Comment: Adding to the comment by @ThomA, the order by columns must be unique for the results to be deterministic.

Comment: Thank you, the question is what if I do not have unique values in any column, is it now default to be by default added column like id?

Comment: @DevMaster Then you should fix that, because that's a significant design flaw with the schema and you won't be able to reliably do this without it. And remember: the uniqueness can cross multiple columns.

Comment: Add an identity field so you will have unique values, why do you want to have unrestricted duplicates though. And most of all, why are you fetching them page-wise. Also, "cells" is an excel concept, databases have columns and rows

Answer (score 1):

You must assure the `ORDER BY` clause gives a **unique** order to the sequence.

In your case, `dob` is not a unique key for the table. Add an order condition that makes it unique: `[id]` after the `[dob]` field.

eg.

```
SELECT [id]
      ,[name]
      ,[dob]
FROM [Production].[dbo].[test]
ORDER by [dob] ASC, [id]
OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Thank you, the question is what if I do not have unique values in any column, is it now default to be by default added column like id?

Comment: having no key into your tables is a devil anti pattern concept.... One way to get around is to use the NEWID() function to generate a dynamic unique data

Comment: The `ORDER BY` has no default, so you must provide a unique order by. Not necessary you must provide a unique field (or a key column), you could provide any combination of fields that make the sort order predictible.

Answer (score 1):

> what if [I] have to use only one column to ORDER BY and some cells may have same value?

That's an artificial constraint you'll need to remove.

Relational databases explicitly disclaim any responsibility at all for preserving any inherent or natural order for data. There is **no such thing as any default or fallback ordering**. A database is free to return data in the order it deems most efficient for the situation, and without explicit `ORDER BY` instructions they can and **will** in some circumstances return different orders for the *same query and source data* from run to run.